# Fast way to get translations of all installed modules

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a site with a lot of modules. Now I need the german translation (if available) of all this modules.

Is there a faster way than downloading and importing them one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Localization Update](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module, it will hold all your modules translated and up-to-date.

> Automatically download and update your translations fetching them from localize.drupal.org or any other Localization server.

Comment: Thx @indrock for the editing.

Comment: my pleasure :-)